# Angular 2 injecting a component (or HTML) into another component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to inject a component (or HTML) into another component. I have one component that will be reusable around my site (a modal), and I want to be able to inject components or html into each modal instance. Shouldn't there be a way to do this?:

```
<some-component>
   <custom-content></custom-content>
</some-component>
```

That would make it so easy. I tried and it didn't work. Is there any way to something similar?

Comment: Are you looking for `<ng-content>`, and the concept of "transclusion"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transclusion and `<ng-content></ng-content>` looks like exactly what I was looking for.